# Python: Print non empty lists when multiple lists are present

Tags: python, list

So let's say I have 10 lists named a-j:

I can check which list is empty

> if a.empty:
>
> do something

But in what way can I print only the non empty lists:

> for all lists in a-j :
> print(non-empty lists)

Comment: if not a.empty: according to your logic and syntax!

Comment: can you show some code to show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

try list comprehensions:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[], [1], [], [2,3],[]]
>>> list_of_lists
[[], [1], [], [2, 3], []]
>>> [ l for l in list_of_lists if l]
[[1], [2, 3]]
```

because and empty list is not **truthy**, `if l` evaluates to false when the list is empty, so it is not witheld.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just check for any element in the list?

```
for list_i in all_lists:
  if list_i:
    print(list_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose that you regrouped your 10 lists in a list L so L is now a list of your 10 lists,so this sample of code print the non empty lists which means those who have more than one element:

`for l in L:
    if (len(l)>0):
        print(l)`